# Use different app display name on SKStoreReviewController and Springboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, skstorereviewcontroller

I have an app called "Inflation Calculator". Since that name is too long to fit on the springboard, I use "Inflation" as the display name.

I'm currently updating the app for iOS 11 and want to make use of the `SKStoreReviewController`, but this is causing me some trouble. `SKStoreReviewController` defaults to using the same display name as the springboard ("Inflation"). This is not the full name of the app, though, so the alert doesn't feel correct.

Ideally, the springboard display name would stay "Inflation" and `SKStoreReviewController` would show the full name "Inflation Calculator". Is it possible to configure the app so that these two names can be different?

[image: SpringBoard display name is "Inflation"] [image: SKStoreReviewController defaults to using the same display name as the SpringBoard, but I want it to say "Inflation Calculator"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem possible at this time. `SKStoreReviewController` runs out-of-process, so you cannot modify it at runtime. It uses the `CFBundleDisplayName` in the app's `Info.plist`, which is the same value displayed on the Springboard.